# 1910b Ugee monitor NO Signal to PC

Tags: windows-10

I'm trying to connect my Ugee to my PC. The tablet has a vga cable but my PC's GTX 1080ti doesn't have a VGA slot. The tablet also has a Dvi slot with the +5 pins while my PC has one but with +1 pin. 
I've bought a few cables already with no progress. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If it *requires* analog input (is it [DVI-I or DVI-A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface#/media/File:DVI_Connector_Types.svg)?), and your PC only provides digital output (DVI-D) you'll likely need to buy a fairly expensive and perhaps somewhat laggy active converter.

Comment: On the tablet monitor its a DVI-I and on my PC it's a DVI-D.

Comment: DVI-D is digital and analog.  However, I do believe DVI-I is digital only, which you are out of luck.  **It's extremely expensive to convert VGA to a digital DVI signal.**

Comment: @Ramhound You have it the wrong way around. -D is digital. -I is both. But some devices use a DVI-I connector while only supporting one of -A or -D. (You also appear to have the conversion direction backwards - the goal here is to go from DVI-D to analog, which is more doable than analog to DVI-D.)

Comment: @user742247, from the [product spec sheet](http://ugee.net/goods/56.html) I would assume that digital DVI-D should be possible here. Are you saying a standard DVI cable does not work? Have you got anything else plugged into the graphics card? Which manufacturer/model is the card, and have you checked which connections can be used simultaneously? (some GPUs might provide 3x DVI ports but 1 of them might be disabled if a DP port is used, etc.)

Comment: @Bob I think I used the wrong Dvi cable. I do have other things plugged in like my hdmi to my tv which I use an monitor. Nivida GTx1080Ti graphics card. I did try unplugging things before to see if it would work and nothing.

Comment: @user742247 Do you have any other monitors/TVs that can take DVI input to test with? Also, FYI, "GTX 1080Ti" is the GPU chip but the card is manufactured by a different OEM, e.g. Gigabyte has [half a dozen](http://www.gigabyte.us/Graphics-Card/GeForce%C2%AE-GTX-10-Series) different 1080Ti cards, MSI has a bunch, Asus, EVGA, etc..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming its VGA only - and your existing slots don't work, you might be able to use a HDMI or Displayport to VGA adaptor instead. These are fairly cheap - get an active one, and should let you use a purely analog VGA device with modern PCs fairly simply.

Comment: I would suggest figuring out why DVI doesn't work, before going and buying a $30 active converter that also reduces quality and introduces latency. This should be a last resort.

Comment: I'm assuming this is the last resort. Also, DVI-I on the *display* side is odd.

Comment: Maybe because it's a drawing tablet monitor? I really have no idea.